# Remy Sharp's function throttler

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, jquery-events

trying to use a throttling function created by Remy Sharp (http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/)... it works in the standard use like so:

```
$('.thing').click(throttle(function() { 
   console.log('api call'); 
}, 300);
```

Which is pretty neat, but I wanted to be able to throttle a specific part of code within a function, not on the entire click event, like so:

```
$('.thing').click(function() { 
    console.log('hello!'); 

    throttle(function() { 
        console.log('api call'); 
    }, 300); 

});
```

But I don't quite understand why it doesn't work. The throttle code returns a function so if I proceed the throttle call with `.apply(this, arguments);` then type 'hello', the function is called 5 times rather than once as the timer within the throttling function isn't being overwritten.

Sifted through the jQuery click code but couldn't really find anything. I'm guessing jQuery creates one instance of it and then recalls the same instance so the same  timer is there?

Does anyone understand this and why it happens like so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong ;-)

Here's the solution on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/elabul/edit

The `throttle` method *returns* a function that will throttle the number of times it's called. So you need to capture that bad boy in a variable and call it from inside your click handler, as such:

```
var inputThrottle = throttle(function () {
  console.log('api call');
}, 250);


$('input').keyup(function () {
   console.log('test');
   inputThrottle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just calling throttle does nothing, you need to return the function as a function to the click handler:

```
$('.thing').click((function() { 
    console.log('hello!'); 

    return throttle(function() { 
        console.log('api call'); 
    }, 300); 

}()));
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Created a fiddle for it as well: http://jsfiddle.net/ME7rm/

Comment: You are right, I forgot to call the function that returns the function to the handler. I updates the answer and your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ME7rm/1/

Answer (score 0):

you need to call returned from throttle function:

```
$('.thing').click(function() { 
    console.log('hello!'); 

    (throttle(function() { 
        console.log('api call'); 
    }, 500))(); 

});
```

Comment: But that doesn't work either. If you type in `test` really quick, it'll call the function 4 times when it should only call it once (when typing in quick succession)

Comment: use debounce instead of throttle, see:  http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: His definition of debounce is pretty much the same as Remy Sharp's throttle (which I guess is better named Choke). I guess his version has a tonne of commenting in the code and will work straight out so I can check that out. Thanks :)